# C++ create custom object

Tags: c++, class, parsing, dynamic, types

I've developed a simple GUI Renderer for my 3D - Engine, wich is able
to parse a script file like this:

```
GUIButton Nameofelement
.pos 10 20
.size 100 50
```

Basically it creates an Object of the type `GUIButton`, names it `Nameofelement` and then applys the properties starting with a `.`

All GUI - Elements are sub-classes of class GUIElement.

My Problem is: Anyone should be able to create own subclasses of GUIElement and register
them for scriptparsing. Something like this:

```
class MyPersonalElement : public GUIElement
{
    //all the stuff that belongs in here
}
```

Now this is the part I'm not sure if it is even possible:

```
GUI->register("GUIPersonal", MyPersonalElement);
```

So that you can use it in the GUI-Script:

```
GUIPersonal personalObject
.property value
```

Currently the script is parsed somewhat like this:

```
GUIElement* currentElement = NULL;

if(input == "GUIButton")
{
    currentElement = new GUIButton();
    //...
}
```

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: You can use a Factory Design Pattern to create your object : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern

Comment: Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern

Comment: As it stands, your question is **too broad**!